# HTTP Request limit with jnetpcap

Tags: java, http-headers, packet-sniffers, jpcap, jnetpcap

i'm developing sniffer in java with eclipse . i can sniff HTTP packet, TCP , UDP . But i need to control or ''state'' if request limit more than 10 in one second. İ know with jnetpcap we can't block , i just want to know it is possible i can get this. Thank you . Below my code

```
PcapPacketHandler <String> jpacketHandler = new PcapPacketHandler<String> () 
{

private final Http h = new Http();
private final Tcp t = new Tcp();


@Override
public void nextPacket(PcapPacket packet, String user) {
 if(packet.hasHeader(h)){

     final JCaptureHeader header = packet.getCaptureHeader();

        System.out.printf("---------1111--------" + header.toString()+ "-------1111--------");
        System.out.printf("packet caplen= %d wiredlen = %d  \n ",
                header.caplen(),header.wirelen());
                System.out.println(packet.toString());
                //   System.out.printf("---------+++++++++--------" + packet.getHeader(h).toString() + "-------++++++--------");
                //packet.getHeader(h).toString();


        //Find if the given packet is a Request/Response Pkt : First get the TCP header 
                packet.getHeader(t);


 }
```